# Searching for specific lines in text files throughout a directory

Tags: bash

Say you have a root directory and you want to go through every subdirectory within that directory and look for any text files that are named "data.txt". You then want to extract any lines from all of the data text files that start with "Results:". You want to print any directory that has a text file named "data" and print any Results lines. For example if the directory structure is:

```
root
directory1:
  data.txt
directory2:
  // no data.txt here
directory3:
  data.txt
```

The output should be:

```
directory1
Results: .5
directory3
Results: .6
Results: .7
```

This is my code so far but it isn't working:

```
for d in */; do
> if [[ -f "data.txt" ]]
> then
> echo “$d”
> grep -h “Results:" $data.txt
> fi
> done
```

When I run this code nothing prints. I think this solution is largely right but I'm having some syntactical issues. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: This is a job for `find`. `for d in */` is not recursive, nor do you actually descend into found directories. This question is too broad - narrow it down to a single problem.

Comment: ah, ok thanks! So I'm doing `find . "data.txt"` but it's still not working. It's showing all the folders within my root directory, including directory1/data.txt, but not going inside of directory1 itself to look for data.txt. How can I make it descend into subdirectories?

Comment: You aren't using `find` correctly.  Look at the man page for the `find -name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your original code with notes about what could be wrong in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# That first line is called shebang, if you're interested

for d in */; do
    # 1. You have to check for data.txt in specific location,
    #    so prepend $d directory from your loop to the path:
    if [[ -f "$d/data.txt" ]]
    then
        # 2. “ and ” are good for casual text, but program code uses simple quotes - "
        # 3. You print the name of the every directory you loop over,
        #    even while there are no "Results:" lines there
        echo "$d"
        # 4. Again, $data.txt is weird path - it will result in
        #    directory name with "ata.txt" in your example,
        #    e.g. directory1/ata.txt
        # -  Minor note: better to use regexp's meta-character "^"
        #    to match "Results:" only in the beginning of the lines
        grep -h "^Results:" "$d/data.txt"
    fi
done
```

This script produces next output:

```
directory1/
Results: .5
directory3/
Results: .6
Results: .7
```

If you want to fix 3rd issue, then you should do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */; do
    if [[ -f "$d/data.txt" ]]; then
        # First, search for the results
        RESULTS=$(grep -h "^Results:" "$d/data.txt")
        # Second, output directory name (and the results)
        # only if the grep output is not empty:
        if [[ -n "$RESULTS" ]]; then
            echo "$d"
            echo "$RESULTS"
        fi
    fi
done

# Produces same output
```

Other part to improve is to support recursive directories to find files like directory/subdirectory/data.txt:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Allow recursive matches
shopt -s globstar

# Loop over the directories recursively:
for dir in **/; do
# ...
# rest of the code
```

And, finally, if you want to output directory names without the trailing slash, like in your example, then:

```
# Instead of
echo "$d"
# Print $d without "/" suffix:
echo "${d%/}"
```

The resulting script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar

for d in **/; do
    if [[ -f "$d/data.txt" ]]; then
        RESULTS=$(grep -h "^Results:" "$d/data.txt")
        if [[ -n "$RESULTS" ]]; then
            echo "${d%/}"
            echo "$RESULTS"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Would produce (I've added example subdirectory):

```
directory1
Results: .5
directory3
Results: .6
Results: .7
directory4/subdir
Results: .9
```